# dpkg-query -l shows removed packages, but dpkg-query -l "pattern" doesn't find them - why?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, uninstall

I've just uninstalled some i386 versions of certain packages. If I execute:

```
dpkg-query --list | grep ":i386"
```

I see them listed. If, however, I execute:

```
dpkg-query ---list "*:i386"
```

I don't see them,nor does `--show` instead of `--list` help.

Can't I search among all packages with dpkg-query itself?

Answer (score 4):

`dpkg-query --list` is documented to take a "package-name-pattern", which is a shell glob-style pattern on the package name. The architecture (the `:i386` bit) isn't part of the package name, so the package-name-pattern can't match it.

You can use `grep-dctrl` (or its aliases, like `grep-status` and `grep-available`) to do this, though. You'll need to install `dctrl-tools` if you don't already have it.

```
grep-status -sPackage --not -FStatus installed --and -FArchitecture i386
```

probably does something similar to what you're looking for. That looks for things in the status file where the Status field doesn't match "installed" and the Architecture field matches "i386".

If you're looking for deinstalled but not purged i386 packages, you could try:

```
grep-status -sPackage -FStatus config-files --and -FArchitecture i386
```

or (as you've probably guessed by now), installed i386 packages:

```
grep-status -sPackage -FStatus installed --and -FArchitecture i386
```

All the `grep-dctrl` variants have plenty of options to specify exactly what to search and which fields to output; the [grep-dctrl manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/grep-dctrl) has details.